# Is it possible to set a RowDefinition Resource to style all TextBlocks in that row?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Grid with a number of TextBlocks.
I want to change the foreground of each TextBlock based on a boolean value in the associated ViewModel.
Each TextBlock in a row uses the same binding from VM to change, so I thought a good way to do it would be to set a Style with a Data Trigger on the GridRow.

I've tried using the following:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
                    <RowDefinition.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TempWarning}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RowDefinition.Resources>
                </RowDefinition>
```

Then I declare the TextBlock like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CurrentTemp}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0"/>
```

However, even though the TempWarning value is set to true, the TextBlock foreground is not updating.

Can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `Style` to `<Grid.Resources>`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TempWarning}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

An implicit resource in `<RowDefinition.Resources>` is *not* applied to an element in the `Grid`.

If you only want the `Style` to apply to a specific row, you could use a `MultiDataTrigger` that also binds to the `Grid.Row` attached property of the `TextBlock` itself:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TempWarning}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Grid.Row),
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: How would I go about this if I need a to colour each row?
They will all be white, but each row will bind to a different warning. That is the only difference.

Comment: Different warning as in different source property? You need to create a style per row.

Comment: Yes, this binding in this line would be different: <Condition Binding="{Binding TempWarning}" Value="True" />
So TempWarning would be TempWarning1 (not real values, just examples), and the value for the Grid.Row would be 1.

I tried creating multiple Styles, but it appears it's not possible to add more than one Style for the same TargetType.

Comment: You can add several `MultiDataTriggers` to the same `Style`.